# I got this warning "attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy" when I try to present a view

Tags: ios, swift, warnings, modalviewcontroller

My view hierarchy looks like image below:[image]

My problem is I want to show VC1 when I click any button on VC3. Here is my code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registerNavigation")
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

but I got this warning "Warning: attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy" and nothing happen. Please tell me, what did I do wrong?

Comment: hello dear kindly have a look of this [article](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-avoid-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy-error-when-presenting-a-uiviewcontroller/) hope this completely solve your problem and understands the root of warning which you are getting  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show VC1 from VC3 the you not need to present it again because it is already loaded in navigation stack. you just need to `dismiss or pop` VC3 and VC2 from navigation stack. If you have presented it then dismiss and if you have pushed it then popped it.

Your warning's meaning :  you are trying to presenting which is in the view hierarchy of navigation controller 1 but not in the view hierarchy of navigation controller 2.!!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: it works like a magic.I just dismiss it and it shows the VC1. Thank you. You save my day.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting to navigationController so use code like below.

```
let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registerNavigation") as! ViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)
self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I got this error when I try to use your code "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'"